# Export Consul nodes from Key/Value store as Prometheus targets

Tags: docker, consul, docker-swarm, prometheus, cadvisor

Prometheus has Consul scraper that reads data about Consuls *services*. But I need something different.

On each consul agent I have cAdvisor installed. Consul agents are registered in Consul Key/Value store under e.g. `MYSWARM/DOCKER/NODES/`. I would like to use these values to get IP addresses of all the nodes, i.e. the cAdvisors.

How can I do that?

P.S. It seems I am searching for Consul KV scraper.

Comment: Do you want to populate your scrape targets from K/V or export the values as some kind of metric?

Answer (score 1):

That sounds kinda custom. Try the File SD http://www.robustperception.io/using-json-file-service-discovery-with-prometheus/

Comment: I can do workaround with files, actually even better - using ansible template. But I was looking for consul KV scraper.